# Hibernate + tomcat Unknown entity

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, resteasy

I'm trying to execute a simple select from database using hibernate and RESTEasy on Tomcat. I've already done it several times and it always worked on JBoss, but now I need to do it on Tomcat. And I keep geting Unknown entity exception.No idea why...
Here is my presistance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="punit">
        <class>swp.model.tables.User</class>
    <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is my User class which maps database table:

```
package swp.model.tables;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: User
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u") })
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String pass;


    public User() {
    }

    public User(String id, String password){
        this.setId(id);
        this.setPass(password);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return this.pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    } 
}
```

And my RESTfull service:

```
@GET
@Path("get/user/{id}/{password}")
@Produces({ "text/xml" })
public String getPrivilege(@PathParam("id") String id,@PathParam("password") String password, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    EntityManager em = Dispenser.getMenager().createEntityManager();
    User user = em.find(User.class, id);
    em.close();
    return user.getPass();
}
```

And here is stacktrace:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: swp.model.tables.User
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:340)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:214)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:540)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: swp.model.tables.User
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:804)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:767)
    swp.server.resources.Database.getPrivilege(Database.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:155)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: swp.model.tables.User
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1028)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:95)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:954)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:870)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:863)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:792)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:767)
    swp.server.resources.Database.getPrivilege(Database.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:155)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: Is your `persistence.xml` deployed under `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF`?

Comment: yes it is. but does it matter that my User class is in seperated project, which is included in server- side project?

Comment: As long as it is included in the runtime class path, I don't think it matters. It looks like it doesn't find the `persistence.xml`, but I don't know why. Can you show the code where you create the EntityManagerFactory?

Comment: I solved the problem by disabling tomcat security manager

Comment: And on JBoss this code works well. So it was tomcat issue

Comment: Ultimately, we need to know what `Dispenser.getMenager()` actually does.  If you can post the code.  Remember that in servlet containers, you need to bootstrap your `EntityManagerFactory`.